# How to get footer to stay at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, footer, sticky

I'm  working placing a sticky footer that stay at the bottom of my sidebar. However, a small issue is bothering me. It appears the footer starts with a margin on the left side but there is no margin on the right. What am I doing wrong here? Please see screenshot below:

[No margin on the right side of the footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ42l.png)

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body {

    background-color: #fff;
}

/* Every CSS rule for the Sidebar and it's contents */

.logo {
    width: 180px;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 14px auto;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../images/logo.png);
}

.sidebar {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#map {
    height: 100vh;
}

.collapse ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.collapse ul li {
    padding: 10px;
}

footer {
    margin: 40px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>TripQuest</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--Custom CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">

    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-KA6wR/X5RY4zFAHpv/CnoG2UW1uogYfdnP67Uv7eULvTveboZJg0qUpmJZb5VqzN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="sidebar col-3">
          <div class="logo"></div>
          <div class="mt-5"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="routename" placeholder="Route Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md btn-block">Submit</button>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-md btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myroutes">My Routes</button>
          <div id="myroutes" class="collapse">
            <div class="mt-3 mb-3">
              <ul>
                <li>10/29/2019 - Roy</li>
                <li>10/12/2019 - Roy</li>
                <li>10/05/2019 - Roy</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="mt-2"></div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-md btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">My Account</button>
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">My Account</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    The user's "My Account" content will go in this modal window.
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          <footer>
              &copy; 2019 TripQuest.org
              
              <div class="mt-4 mt-b-3">
                  <i class="fab fa-2x fa-facebook-square" style="padding-right: 10px"></i>
                  <i class="fab fa-2x fa-twitter-square"></i>
              </div>
          </footer>
        </div>
        <div id="map" class="mapsec col-9" style="background-color: #f5f7f8;">Google Maps</div>

        <script>
            // Initialize and add the map
            function initMap() {
              // The location of Uluru
              var uluru = {lat: 38.897663, lng: -77.036575};
              // The map, centered at Uluru
              var map = new google.maps.Map(
                  document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 13, center: uluru});
              // The marker, positioned at Uluru
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
            }
                </script>
                <!--Load the API from the specified URL
                * The async attribute allows the browser to render the page while the API loads
                * The key parameter will contain your own API key (which is not needed for this tutorial)
                * The callback parameter executes the initMap() function
                -->
                <script async defer
                src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyACgLN4EW-PpbSRRzZm5iBGeDcgS1OKLHQ&callback=initMap">
                </script>
            
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `col-3` class on your sidebar is adding a 15px padding to the left and right sides of the node parenting your sticky footer. The top-left corner of the footer starts inside the padding, which is clearly not what you want.

The simplest solution, albeit a little janky, is to offset the padding by using a negative margin on your footer. Using a negative margin will help you position in a relative fashion on an absolutely-positioned element. That would look like:

```
...

footer {
    margin: 40px 0 40px -15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
}

...
```

These types of layouts are exactly what CSS grids were designed for, so if you have the flexibility to explore CSS grids, I would do so. You can find documentation on CSS grids here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout